# Get blob image from file input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, file

I am having some problems to take image as blob using jQuery:

Here is my code:

```
var file = $("#imgGaleria3")[0].files;

if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // browser completed reading file - display it
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
}
```

And all the time im getting the same error:
    uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

How can I solve? I try some methods to read the data from file object with FileReader but nothing solves my problem.

Thx for ur help guys

Comment: you should put `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` after assigning the `reader.onload`.

and `$("#imgGaleria3")[0].files` is an array of files . 
 you should use `$("#imgGaleria3")[0].files[0]`

Comment: I dont understand why i should put : reader.readAsDataURL(file); after the reader.onload but u have the reason with the array of files.. thx too mate

Comment: Because it may finish reading the file even before attaching the on load function .

Comment: And how can i store this value? I need to store three images and some data more and have some problems because this func its async..

Comment: You should put the same function at the end of each onload function, this function does tow things , first it makes sure all 3 are loaded or else it stoppes . if all 3 images are loaded it continues to execute.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This line looks wrong:

```
var file = $("#imgGaleria3")[0].files;
```

You need `file` to be a single file not all the files.

Example:

```
var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
```

or jQuery way:

```
var file = $("#imgGaleria3")[0].files[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

you're trying to execute the reader on an array.

try

```
var file = $("#imgGaleria3")[0].files[0];

if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // browser completed reading file - display it
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks, I test using Jquery fileinput plugin and it's works